# Trying to identify this resistor, it's from a 240v mains 12v battery charger,

Tags: resistors, identification

Trying to identify this resistor, it's  from a 240v mains 18v battery charger for Black and Decker drill.[image]

Comment: Have you checked it against the resistor color code?

Comment: That is a resistor with color codes charred beyond recognition. It cannot be identified.